# Trying to create a button per object instance

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-1.9

I'm trying to make a list of buttons, each corresponding to an object in my database. However, when I press one of them, it is always the value of the last button generated which is sent back to the view:

```
        {% if segmenter %}
        <form method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <ul>
            {% for segment in segments %}
            <li>
                <input type="hidden" name="id" value="{{ segment.pk }}"/>
                <button type="submit">{{ segment }}</button>
            </li>
            {% endfor %}
        </ul>
        {% else %}
            <strong>No segments registered. </strong><br />
        {% endif %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Form items are distinguished by `name` but you're using the same `name` for your inputs. Besides using one form means you intend to send all the inputs when the inputs are differentiated.

You should do:

```
{% if segmenter %}
{% csrf_token %}
<ul>
    {% for segment in segments %}
    <form method="post">
    <li>
        <input type="hidden" name="id_{{ segment.pk }}" value="{{ segment.pk }}"/>
        <button type="submit">{{ segment }}</button>
    </li>
    </form>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
{% else %}
    <strong>No segments registered. </strong><br />
{% endif %}
```

which posts a separate form on click of each button